# UIGestureRecognizer not invoked

Tags: ios, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

I explored numerous SO posts for an answer, but I cannot get this to work.

I have a UICollectionView. The UICollectionViewCell is created programmatically. I want to act on the click of a subview of UICollectionViewCell, and no action for click on rest of the UICollectionViewCell.

Below is the code for UICollectionViewCell.

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    let bgImageViewTop = UIImageView()
    addSubview(bgImageViewTop)

    // constraints...

    bgImageViewTop.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    bgImageViewTop.addGestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleClick(_:))))
}

func handleClick(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("click")
}
```

The function handleClick is never invoked. bgImageViewTop has no subviews.

I tried overriding hitTest to check what is happening, like so:

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    let view = super.hitTest(point, with: event)

    print("hittest \(view)")
    return view
}
```

Clicking on bgImageViewTop produces the following logs, which shows that the click is going to the right place

```
hittest Optional(<UIImageView: 0x7fc143413750; frame = (0 0; 240 160); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60800024e400>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000003ffe0>>)
```

I verified that UIImageView reference in the logs above refer to bgImageViewTop.

Am I missing something small here?

Comment: You create `UIGestureRecognizer` but in handler you use `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Is it by design or just a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `UITapGestureRecognizer`, which inherits from `UIGestureRecognizer`.

[Obligatory link to the documentation for it.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer)

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Learning for self: "if cant find a solution online, the issue is a dumb stupid miss in your own code!"